# How do I remove the first characters from the Rightof a specific column in a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I remove things after a characters (-) from the right of a specific column in a table?

Column name is location.

```
Amsterdam - park - station 7
Rotterdam - van Nellefabriek - straatweg 7
Utrecht - Amsterdamsestraatweg 10
```

want to see:

```
Amsterdam - park
Amsterdam - park
Rotterdam - van Nellefabriek 
Utrecht
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, tokens VARCHAR(1000));
INSERT INTO @tbl (tokens) VALUES 
('Amsterdam - park - station 7'),
('Rotterdam - van Nellefabriek - straatweg 7'),
('Utrecht - Amsterdamsestraatweg 10'),
('Assen');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT t.*
    , LEFT(tokens, LEN(tokens) - CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(tokens))) AS Result
FROM @tbl AS t;
```

**Output**

```
+----+--------------------------------------------+------------------------------+
| ID |                   tokens                   |            Result            |
+----+--------------------------------------------+------------------------------+
|  1 | Amsterdam - park - station 7               | Amsterdam - park             |
|  2 | Rotterdam - van Nellefabriek - straatweg 7 | Rotterdam - van Nellefabriek |
|  3 | Utrecht - Amsterdamsestraatweg 10          | Utrecht                      |
|  4 | Assen                                      | Assen                        |
+----+--------------------------------------------+------------------------------+
```

Comment: works only,    Lichtenvoorde - Varsseveldseweg 8-12 wil be  Lichtenvoorde - Varsseveldseweg 8

Comment: The proposed solution does exactly what was asked in the original question. I also asked for a minimal reproducible example: ##1-4